# I have a listbox issue with GetItemText, Replace it and Add it to the list

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

First of all sorry for my bad english but im italian.

Second, i only program from 4 months and im pretty bad...

So, I were doing a music player with Windows Forms, you can open a folder with music files and listen to them so when it open the folder, it takes all the files and put it in the listbox but they are like "C:\Desktop\Folder\AllStar.mp3" and i only wanted it like "AllStar.mp3" so i made this code **but when I run it, it creates a thing, in italian its (Raccolta) [with google translator is (Collection) or (Gathering)] and it doesn't gives me the Replaced files with the short name**, how can I fix that?

This is the code

```
string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items);
text = text.Replace(@"C:\Users\****\****\Desktop\-PC-\Musica", "");
listBox1.Items.Add(text);
```

It will help a lot!

Comment: Look at `Path.GetFilename` it's the best way to extract the name from a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetFileName` to only retrieve the filename without the extension.

**Full Example**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListBoxExample
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var browser = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                DialogResult result = browser.ShowDialog();

                if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(browser.SelectedPath))
                {
                    var files = Directory
                        .GetFiles(browser.SelectedPath)
                        .Where(path => Path.GetExtension(path).ToUpper().EndsWith("MP3"))
                        .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path));

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        MusicListBox.Items.Add(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT! You helped me sooo much, now it perfectly work and i can also choose the type of file to take!!! Thank you! ❤❤❤

Comment: @ApplePie are you able to click the tick on this answer saying this is the accepted answer